# What is the error in below code of re.findall()?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
import re
for test in range(int(input())):
    a = input()                  # input a string
    n = a.replace("=", "")       # if string contains '='then remove it
    gg = re.findall(r ">+", n)   # count >
    l1 = len(max(gg, key = len)) # count consecutive >
    hh = re.findall(r "<+", n)   # count <
    l2 = len(max(hh, key = len)) # count consecutive <
    print(max(l1, l2) + 1)       # print max of two + 1
```

Input is :
4
<<<
<><
<=>
<=<
I am encountering a error if I run the above code.I read it on SO only the syntax still I am getting error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>   File "/home/fea0d5e04ac92cb3a1e4f041940f2dfc.py", line 8, in <module><br/>
> l2=len(max(hh, key=len))<br/> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
> ```

Comment: Please include the error you're getting. When I run the code, it works fine.

Comment: @user3080953 edited it

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: `>>>>>>>` triggers it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max` fails on an empty sequence.

## Python >= 3.4

[max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) takes an optional default argument:

`l1 = len(max(gg, key = len, default=0)) # count consecutive >`

## Python < 3.4

Add a guard to check if the list is empty

```
if len(hh) > 0: 
    l2 = len(max(hh, key = len)) # count consecutive <
else:
    l2 = 0
```